# Error:NO database is selected

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I tried it connection to database connection to database is successful but when i try to match user information with database it gives me a error NO database is selected
i tried it connecting to database using different method but nothing worked

```
<?php
//CREATING CONNECTION TO DATABASE
$con= new mysqli("localhost", "****", "***", "*****");
$con->select_db("lel_server_user_db_secured");
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Problem With connection to database Please contact administrator regarding this error";
    }
/* RETURNS NAME OF DEFAULT DATABASE
if ($result = $con->query("SELECT DATABASE()")) {
    $row = $result->fetch_row();
    printf("Default database is %s.\n", $row[0]);
    $result->close();
}
*/
/*
$host="localhost";
$db_user="sky.xpert";
$db_pass="havefun344";
$database="lel_server_user_db_secured";
mysqli_connect($host,$db_user,$db_pass,$database) or die ("Failed to connect");
mysqli_select_db($database) ;
*/

session_start();

//GATHERING DATA FROM USER FORM
$email=$_POST["login"];
$pass=$_POST["pwd"];

//COMMANDING WHERE TO FIND MATCH FOR LGOIN INFORMATION
$veryfy="SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email='$email' Password='$pass'";
$query=mysql_query($veryfy) or die ( mysql_error() );

$match=0;
$match=mysql_num_rows($query);

//IF MATCH FOUND THEN SETTING SESSION AND REDIRECTING IT TO LOGGED PAGE
if($match==1)
    {
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = "true";
        header ("Location: logged.php"); //REDIRECTING USER TO ITS HOMEPAGE
    }
else //IF MATCH NOT FOUND THEN REDIRECTING IT BACK TO LOGIN PAGE
    {
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = "false";
        header ("Location: index.php");
    }
//PERSONAL COMMENTS OR DETIALED COMMENTS
//PROBLEM WITH THIS SCRIPT GIVING OUTPUT ON LOGIN "NO DATABASE SELECTED"
//REFRENCE from http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/52783-basic-login-script-with-php/

?>
```

Comment: +1 for not using `mysql_*`

Comment: -1 for "not using mysql_" is not a merit. Yet using mysql_* is not a shame.

Comment: -1 for the same reason as YCS told ... and @RPM why you think mysql_* is bad .. ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can simply do it by

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
```

there is no need to do `$con->select_db("lel_server_user_db_secured");` again

and using mysqli isnt mean your code is safe ... your code is still ***vulnerable to SQL injection*** Use ***prepared statement*** instead or atleast [**`mysqli_real_escape_string`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

You need to escape all request properly

and its possible that your database isnt exist so check that its exist first

### **AND you are mixing tow different API**

you can not use `MySQLi` functions  with `MySQL_*` function

Comment: Answers to a question should contain the answer to the question. You should add this as a comment instead.

Comment: @Sumurai8 i think i am trying to answering the question ]

Comment: Even i have very little rep ... i have no problem with downvote .. but please tell me reason so that i can improve my answer

Comment: @Sumurai8 and please tell me how can i format comment like my answer

Comment: You can use backticks (`) in your comments to format code and single and double stars to create italic and bold. I downvoted the answer, because your original answer didn't contain an answer to the question and the downvote is now locked in place until a visible edit is made.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't edit your question to add other people's answers to it if it doesn't add a detail to your own answer (which in this case it doesn't) and you are encouraged to use proper grammar (a line starts with a capital and ends with a full stop usually). Try to not use too much style formatting tools. In above answer you are already using bold to emphasize something and using a section header to emphasize something is overkill.

Comment: My database exist and i used this first
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
but it shows me error No database is selected so i 
used this 
$con->select_db("lel_server_user_db_secured");
command too to select database

Is this problem is causing due to i am using two different functions together mysqli and mysql ?

Answer (score 2):

You are initializing a connection to your database with `mysqli`. Then you try to do queries with `mysql`. Obviously, there is no connection with the database made through that library, and therefore it fails with an error. Change `mysql_query` to `mysqli_query`.

**General note**

Your current code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks, because you do not sanitize the input from the user before putting it in a query. Consider using [prepared queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: when i change it to mysqli it gives
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in D:\Documents\Projects\Link e-learn\Website\login1.php on line 32

when i add another parameter in it it gives me this error
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in D:\Documents\Projects\Link e-learn\Website\login1.php on line 32

Which parameter should i use here.

Answer (score 0):

The database `lel_server_user_db_secured` may be not exist.

Content to your mysql:

```
 mysql -hlocalhost -uusername -p
```

then input your password. After login, type command:

```
show databases;
```

check if `lel_server_user_db_secured` is in the result.

**update1***

change the code below:

```
$veryfy="SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email='$email' Password='$pass'";
$query=mysql_query($veryfy) or die ( mysql_error() );

$match=0;
$match=mysql_num_rows($query);
```

to:

```
$veryfy="SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email='$email' Password='$pass'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $veryfy) or die ( mysqli_connect_errno() );

$match=0;
$match=mysqli_num_rows($result);
var_dump($match);
```

Comment: Random note: You are encouraged not to put the password in the command line, as it leaks your password to other users using the same machine/shared server.

Comment: @Sumurai8, thank you for your note. I updated the answer. You can have a look at it.

Comment: Seems okay to me now, but while `-p` would be written against the flag, I think `-u` and `-h` could be written with a space. I am not 100% sure if that is mandatory or not.

Comment: In [`mysql refman`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/command-line-options.html) `-h` and `-u` will be ok in the both form. And if `-p` is given, the password should after  `-p`. Anyway, in GNG `getopt`, it suggest that use blank to split. And I also think that wolud be more readable. tks again. :)

Comment: i have verified the database exist and i tired your method it shows the name of database but when i run the script it shows no database is selected

Comment: Well that worked but now the script is not working... it does nothing it is not redirecting me to any page.

Comment: @user2803557, I updated the answer again. `$match=mysqli_num_rows($result);` if still does not work, add `var_dump($match);` to check the value.

Comment: Still not working ..
Can you help me out in creating secure login script

Comment: What does var_dump ouput?

Answer (score -1):

In the first half of your program you have used *mysqli* and in the latter half *mysql*. Either use *mysqli* or *mysql*. I would recommend using *mysqli* in your entire program so that you are not vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: mysqli doesn't 'automatically' protect against sql injection. `mysqli_query( "SELECT a from b WHERE a='{$_POST['b']}'" )` is just as vulnerable to sql injection as it's `mysql_query` counterpart.

Comment: @Sumurai8 yes, obviously i am aware of the fact that you have to use bind parameters. It wasn't clear in my answer stated. I will try to be more specific next time. Thanks!